# How would I create a method that checks if a move is legal for a checkers game?

Tags: java

I am currently making a checkers game in java and I can't figure out how to test if a move is legal or not. I have created a boolean method but can't get it to change from false to true based on the users move. Currently the player can move pieces where ever with no illegal moves. In the main method I have an if statement based on if the boolean isLegal is true, in the method however I can't figure out how to actually check the users move.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gameboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       String[][] board = setUpBoard();
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
       while (gameIsNotOver(board)) {
           printBoard(board);
           int[] move = getUserInput(scnr);
           if (isLegal(board, move)) {
               updateBoard(board, move);
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("Not a legal move. Try again.");
               continue;
           }
           makeComputerMove(board);
       }
       System.out.println("GAME OVER!");
    }
   
    public static String[][] setUpBoard() {
          
       String[][] board = new String [9][9];
       for (int i=0; i < board.length; i++) {
           for (int j=0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
               board[i][j] = "";
           }
       }
       board[0][1] = "1";// Numbers for top.
       board[0][2] = "2";
       board[0][3] = "3";
       board[0][4] = "4";
       board[0][5] = "5";
       board[0][6] = "6";
       board[0][7] = "7";
       board[0][8] = "8";
       
       board[1][0] = "1"; //numbers for side.
       board[2][0] = "2";
       board[3][0] = "3";
       board[4][0] = "4";
       board[5][0] = "5";
       board[6][0] = "6";
       board[7][0] = "7";
       board[8][0] = "8";
       
       board[8][1] = "WP";
       board[8][3] = "WP";
       board[8][5] = "WP";
       board[8][7] = "WP";
       board[7][2] = "WP";
       board[7][4] = "WP";
       board[7][6] = "WP";
       board[7][8] = "WP";
       board[6][1] = "WP";
       board[6][3] = "WP";
       board[6][5] = "WP";
       board[6][7] = "WP";
       
       board[1][2] = "BP";
       board[1][4] = "BP";
       board[1][6] = "BP";
       board[1][8] = "BP";
       board[2][1] = "BP";
       board[2][3] = "BP";
       board[2][5] = "BP";
       board[2][7] = "BP";
       board[3][2] = "BP";
       board[3][4] = "BP";
       board[3][6] = "BP";
       board[3][8] = "BP";
       
       for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
           for (int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
               System.out.print(board[i][j] + "     " ); //should numbers across the top
           }
       }   
       System.out.println();
       
       return board;
   }   
    
   public static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
   
       boolean iswhite = true;
       String emptyBlack = "      ";
       String emptyWhite = "******";
   
       for (int i=1; i< board.length; i++) {
           for (int j=1; j< board[i].length; j++) {
               if (iswhite) {
                   System.out.print(emptyWhite);
               } else {
                   System.out.print(emptyBlack);
               }
               iswhite = !iswhite;
           }   
           System.out.println();
           
           for (int j=1; j< board[i].length; j++) {
               if (iswhite) {
                   if (board[i][j].equals("")) {
                       System.out.print(emptyWhite);
                   }   else {  
                   System.out.print("**" + board[i][j] + "**");
                   }
               } else {
                   if (board[i][j].equals("")) {
                       System.out.print(emptyBlack);
                   } else {    
                       System.out.print("  " + board[i][j] + "  ");
                   }
               }   
               iswhite = !iswhite;
           }
           
           System.out.println();
           
           for (int j=1; j< board[i].length; j++) {
               if (iswhite) {
                   System.out.print(emptyWhite);
               } else {
                   System.out.print(emptyBlack);
               }
               iswhite = !iswhite;
           }   
           System.out.println();
           
           iswhite=!iswhite;
       }   
   
   }

   public static boolean gameIsNotOver(String[][] board) {
       return true;
   }

   public static int[] getUserInput(Scanner s) {
       System.out.println(" Enter move (start row start column) (end row end column). ");
       
       int[] retVal = new int[4];
       for (int i = 0; i < retVal.length; i++) {
           retVal[i] = s.nextInt();
       }   
       return retVal;  
   }

   public static boolean isLegal(String[][] board, int[] move) {     
      String emptyblack = "      ";
      boolean isLegal = true;
      while (board[move[2]][move[3]] == emptyblack){
          isLegal = true;
      }  
      return isLegal;   
   } 

   public static void updateBoard(String[][] board, int[] move) {    
       board[move[2]][move[3]] = board[move[0]][move[1]];
       board[move[0]][move[1]] = "";
         
   } 
 
   public static void makeComputerMove(String[][] board) {
   }  
        
}
```

Comment: You should be initializing `isLegal = false`.

Comment: 1) You should probably change the methods from "static".  2) Among other things, this will let you make "board[][]" a class member (instead of passing it from function to function as a parameter. 3) Indentation is Important :)  4) To answer your question... `boolean isLegal()` is a good start ... but you never, under any circumstances, ever set it to "false" ;)  Your "while" loop never seems to change, either :(

Answer (score 0):

```java
printBoard(board);
int[] move = getUserInput(scnr);
if (isLegal(board, move)) {
    updateBoard(board, move);
}
```

I'd start by changing this to:

```java
String move = "";
do {
    move = getUserInput(scnr);
} while (!isLegal(board, move, activePlayer);
updateBoard(board, move);
```

This forces the logic to get a valid move before updating the board. I've included `activePlayer` as an input since you need to know who's go it is in order to determine whether a move is legal or not.  You can add active player as part of the overall game state to maintain. Simply switch it after each move is successfully made.

Knowing the board, the proposed move, and which player's turn it is should give you enough info to write the logic to check whether a move is legal or not. I don't remember the exact rules, but each piece on a given square could maintain some state about itself so that determining various properties is easily obtained.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and help. I've never made a randomizer and was wanting to randomize the moves made by the computer. How would I go about that?

Comment: `Random random = new Random();` `int bound = 2` `int nextMode = random.nextInt(bound)` - here the bound `2` represents the number of possible moves on a checkers board (`0`,`1`) - `0` would be forwards 1 and left 1, `1` would be forwards 1 and right 1. Once you have a promoted piece the random upper bound could be 4 since you can move backwards+forwards. There may also be reason to make this recurring when taking pieces.